# Select Columns Of Function Beside Another Column In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following `Persons` table:

```
 Code |   Name  |  Family
 -----+---------+------------
 152  |    A    |    D
 247  |    B    |    E  
 369  |    C    |    F
```

And I have a function that calculates a detail of a person specified using the code field:

```
FnDetailPerson(Persons.Code)
```

The function result is one row of details about the person:

```
   Age  |   Group   |  Sex
 -------+-----------+------------
    30  |     G1    |   0
```

How can I write a `SELECT` query that obtains a result like this?:

```
 Code |   Name  |  Family  |  Age  |   Group   |  Sex
 -----+---------+----------+-------+-----------+-------
 152  |    A    |    D     |   30  |     G2    |   0
 247  |    B    |    E     |   44  |     G1    |   1
 369  |    C    |    F     |   25  |     G2    |   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this not as simple as...

```
SELECT *
FROM Persons P
     CROSS APPLY dbo.fnDetailPerson(P.Code) DP;
```

This is a bit of a guess, as we don't actually have any SQL to work with here.

Comment: No worries, @McNets